# Connecting a user model and event model in rails with foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller, foreign-keys

--UPDATE: I've been doing some more reading and it looks like I should be adding a foreign key - could someone show me how I'd go about doing this? Should I be removing those extra fields I created?

--

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm having trouble with some basic concepts. I've just finished Michael Hartl's book, and I'm using a RailsApps bootstrap-devise-cancan template to start on my first app.

I have a User model and an Event model. I want users to be able to post many events and also attend many events. I added the fields events_attending and created_events to the User table, and the Event table includes users_attending and user_created. I am trying to make it so that when the 'create an event' form is submitted, the user_created field is filled with whichever user posted the event, and that event id is recorded in the users table under created_events.

I've added to the Event model:

```
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :users
```

and to the User model (although I'm not sure if this is correct given that users can belong to multiple events. I looked into has_and_belongs_to_many and thought maybe that was the way to go..):

```
  has_many :events
  belongs_to :event
```

I'm lost as to what to put in the controllers to achieve the desired affect. This is what is currently in the events controller:

```
  def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

What should I be adding to the controller, and what else am I missing? Let me know if any more code needs to be seen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is available in the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and [other places](https://www.google.se/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enSE506SE506&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=sv&safe=off&tbo=d&rlz=1C5CHFA_enSE506SE506&sclient=psy-ab&q=railscasts%20relations&oq=railscasts%20relations&gs_l=serp.3..0i30j0i8i30.18651.22219.0.22356.16.11.5.0.0.1.113.684.10j1.11.0...0.0...1c.1.iMFnw2a94o8&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b248e523acf60cd1&biw=1592&bih=838&ion=1). It's clear that you have not grasped the basics of model relations and you should read up on it a bit more. I'll try to help you:

The Users has_many events is the relation for an event that a user has created. That relation is modeld in the database as a user_id column on the Event table. So when a user creates an event that users id is saved in the event record as user_id. Rails then gives you helper methods such as user.events to get all the events that the user has created.

The other relation, users attending events, needs a separate table. You can see why by examining the relation. The one between user and event above is a one to many relation, A user can cerate many events but each event belongs to exactly one user. The relation here is a many to many relation, an event can be visited by many users and each user can visit many events. There is no way to store that information in a normalized way in a relational database. No matter what side of the relation you look at, user or event, the data is an array...

The solution to this is a join table, a table where you have pairs of user_ids and event_ids. Rails can handle this kind of relation as well, it's called a [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) relation or habtm for short. Googling that will give you information on how to set it up and work with it.

I'll throw in another note: If you only want to look at the relation from one point of view, as in you will be calling user.event_visits but never event.visiting_users you can get away with a column in the user model and skip the join table. What you need is a [serialized column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834902/rails-3-serialize) of event_ids that you can then use to get all the events that user will visit. Working with the data this way is not normalized (and thus frowned upon by DBAs) but can be reasonable depending on your needs. It will require a bit more work on your part thoguh.